# Is there a Microsoft Exchange ODBC Driver?

Tags: odbc, exchange-server

I want to be able to query an Exchange address book via ODBC. It seems like there ought to be a driver available for this puprose but I can't find one.

MS Access can link the Exchange table, and I can then query the Access database via ODBC, but it is pitifully slow.

For the record, I'm not programming so I don't need ADO connection strings or whathaveyou. The database software I'm using (Drawbase, a space database for facilities management) needs an ODBC system data source so I need an ODBC appropriate driver so I can create one.

Answer (score 1):

There is one here:
http://www.connect-gate.com/index.php/en/why-connect-gate/sql-for-communication

It's quite fast and cover the most important SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like it might have solved my problem but I ended up with a more direct solution. I got our DB admin to push the data I needed directly to the SQL database supporting my application, obviating the need for an Exchange ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a fair amount of ODBC work and also run Exchange and I've never heard of one. :(

Answer (score 0):

CData seems to provide the driver now: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/exchange/odbc/  - not sure if this is the same as the Connect Gate driver above or not.